# And Operation between lists of Enums

Tags: c#, enums, logical-operators

I have two lists of Enums and I want to perform And kind of operation between them. Let suppose my enum definition has 3 elements true, false and NA.

```
public enum myEnum {
    True,
    False,
    NA
}
```

I have two lists List1 and List2 and both contain 10 elements. I want these results:

```
True && False = False
True && NA = NA
False && NA = False
True && True = True
False && False = False
NA && NA =  NA
```

I want to know to that is there any built-in functionality in C# which can give me results which I mentioned above. I am trying to avoid writinig long code.

Comment: Why not use a `bool?` instead of that enum?

Comment: Do you mean you want to apply an operation to `listA[0]` and `listB[0]` etc? It's very unclear how the lists come into it and what the output should be.

Comment: @Servy: I have three possible values and due to which I can not use bool

Comment: @User1551892 I didn't suggest using a `bool`, I suggested using a `bool?`, a nullable boolean.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I showed the format of output in my question. I have two list of type of myEnum and I want to perform some operation which I tried to explain in my question. Both list having same length.

Comment: @Survey: Its my mistake. I did not read carefully.

Comment: @User1551892: Oh, I thought that was just a definition of some of the result of various possibilities. The fact that you say the lists have 10 elements and then you list 6 elements makes it very unclear.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I did not mention repeated combinations.

Comment: So do you want deduping as well? Basically your question is horribly unclear at the moment. It's really worth separating out the matter of "I want an operation which acts on two values and gives me one back" and the matter of "I want to provide two input lists and get one output list, applying the same operation to each pair of elements."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start out writing the method that can perform the And operation that you want on just two values, using the logic that you described.  This is actually handled quite easily, as if either value is `False` you return `False`, if none is `False` and one is `NA` you return `NA`, and if both are true you return true, the only remaining case.

```
public static myEnum And(this myEnum first, myEnum second)
{
    if (first == myEnum.False || second == myEnum.False)
        return myEnum.False;
    if (first == myEnum.NA || second == myEnum.NA)
        return myEnum.NA;
    return myEnum.True;
}
```

Next, it appears that you want to compare the item from each list that is at the same index, so the first is compared to the first, the second to the second, etc., to create a new list of the same size as the other two.  You can use `Zip`, to perform this logical operation using the method we've already defined:

```
var query = list1.Zip(list2, (a,b) => a.And(b));
```

Answer (score 2):

A `bool?` (`Nullable<bool>`) has three values and gives you all of the values you expect if you use the logical and (`&`) operator:

```
(bool?)true  & (bool?)false = false
(bool?)true  & (bool?)null  = null
(bool?)false & (bool?)null  = false
(bool?)true  & (bool?)true  = true
(bool?)false & (bool?)false = false
(bool?)null  & (bool?)null  = null
```